# General search for changes in every branch

Tags: git

I am on a project where I have 6 branches, there are 2 main branches: `develop` and `master`.

I am on `develop` right now, and lets say that I want to check if there are changes in the other branches, is there a way to check that from my branch? or I need to go over every single branch ?

Comment: Changes from where?  A remote repo that you fetched from?

Comment: @ThomasStringer no no, all I need is to know if the other branches has changes, like when you are in your branch and you do: `git status` to check what is going on in your branch, I want something like that to check whether the other co-workers are working on something :)

Comment: If you use a service (Github, bitbucket, assembla) they have nice UI's to compare branches.  Based on your comment, you won't be able to see co-wokers changes unless they commit them and push them to the server.

Comment: @SunilD. nope, when you are in your branch and you do `git status` you can see the changes you have done in your branch without commiting :)

Comment: That's correct. But how are you proposing to see what other developers have changed, unless they have committed their changes? You'd have to go and use their computer and run `git status`.

Comment: @SunilD. as we have remote branches I thought It was an option, that is why I am here :)

Comment: @SunilD. but OK, lets say that I want to see the changes and last commits from the terminal, is that possible?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Ah, I got it.  You're talking about stashing uncommitted changes when switching to different branches.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Uncommitted changes

What you're talking about (***uncommitted changes*** either in the working directory or the index) would be accomplished by ["stashing" changes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) before switching to a different branch for difference work:

```
$ git stash
```

And then if you want to see what is stashed in the repository, you can simply run:

```
$ git stash list
```

That'll list out the stash index and the branch/commit that the uncommitted changes reside on.

This is provided you're looking to find out *uncommitted* changes across different commits/branches.

### Committed changes

If you just want to see different ***committed changes*** across the branches, [any variation of `git log` would suffice](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --online --all
```

That's the typical one-liner I use for `git log`.

Both of these approaches should suffice in seeing committed and uncommitted changes across all branches/commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a graph of all commits on all branches (including remote branches) by running `git log --oneline ---graph --all`. If you're looking for changes on a remote branch, be sure to run `git fetch` first to ensure that those branches are up to date with what's on the server.

Note that this only works for committed changes that have been pushed to the remote. Uncommitted changes or changes that haven't been pushed are not visible using this method.

Comment: I am there but how could I exit ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer In git bash just type "q".